# didChangeConnectionState never called on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, gkmatchmaker

This is a weird problem. My program is working fine with my iPhones, but not with the iPads.

On iPhones the GKMatch delegate is called as normal, but on an iPad 2 and on an iPad mini the didChangeConnectionState function is never called.

Is there any solution out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was digging into the problem. It seems that the program is working well between the iPad and another real device, but it is not working between an iPad and the simulator on a computer.